# Python Pandas groupby, row value to column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, transpose

I have a DataFrame which I want to transpose:
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

sid= '13HKQ0Ue1_YCP-pKUxFuqdiqgmW_AZeR7P3VsUwrCnZo' # spreadsheet id
gid = 0 # sheet unique id (0 equals sheet0)
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}/export?gid={}&format=csv'.format(sid,gid)

df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

What I want to do is get the StoreName and CATegory as column header and have weights vs price for every category.

Desired Output :
[image]

I have tried Loops, Pandas but cannot figure it out,

I thought it could have been done by df.GroupBy but the returned object is not a DataFrame.

I get all this from a JSON output of an API:

[API Link for 1STORE](https://weedmaps.com/api/web/v1/listings/maggie-s-farm-medical/menu?type=dispensary)

```
import pandas as pd
import json, requests
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge
page = requests.get(mainurl)

dict_dta = json.loads(page.text) # load in Python DICT

list_columns = ['id', 'name', 'category_name', 'ounce', 'gram', 'two_grams', 'quarter', 'eighth','half_ounce','unit','half_gram'] # get the unformatted output

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(dict_dta, ['categories', ['items']]).pipe(lambda x: x.drop('prices', 1).join(x.prices.apply(lambda y: pd.Series(merge(y)))))[list_columns]
df.to_csv('name')
```

**I have tried tons of methods.
If someone could just point me in the right direction, it would be very helpful.**

Comment: Data as text please, not pictures.

Comment: [Input](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13HKQ0Ue1_YCP-pKUxFuqdiqgmW_AZeR7P3VsUwrCnZo/edit?usp=sheets_home&ths=true)   [Output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RCyVYBKIyIJxV4K-IJLhxu3c04KRL2LirwjfZleoc98/edit#gid=0) Sorry it didnot let me post link in Question.

Comment: That should give you a hint that you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in the right direction?

```
import pandas as pd

sid= '13HKQ0Ue1_YCP-pKUxFuqdiqgmW_AZeR7P3VsUwrCnZo' # spreadsheet id
gid = 0 # sheet unique id (0 equals sheet0)
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{}/export?gid={}&format=csv'.format(sid,gid)

df = pd.read_csv(url)

for idx, dfx in df.groupby(df.CAT):
    if idx != 'Flower':
        continue
    df_test = dfx.drop(['CAT','NAME'], axis=1)
    df_test = df_test.rename(columns={'StoreNAME':idx}).set_index(idx).T

df_test
```

Returns:

```
Flower     Pueblo West Organics - Adult Use  Pueblo West Organics - Adult Use  \
UNIT                                    NaN                               NaN   
HALFOUNCE                              15.0                              50.0   
EIGHTH                                  NaN                              25.0   
TWOGRAMS                                NaN                               NaN   
QUARTER                                 NaN                              40.0   
OUNCE                                  30.0                              69.0   
GRAM                                    NaN                               9.0   

Flower     Pueblo West Organics - Adult Use  Three Rivers Dispensary - REC  \
UNIT                                    NaN                            NaN   
HALFOUNCE                              50.0                           75.0   
EIGHTH                                 25.0                           20.0   
TWOGRAMS                                NaN                            NaN   
QUARTER                                40.0                           45.0   
OUNCE                                  69.0                          125.0   
GRAM                                    9.0                            8.0   

Flower     Three Rivers Dispensary - REC  
UNIT                                 NaN  
HALFOUNCE                           75.0  
EIGHTH                              20.0  
TWOGRAMS                             NaN  
QUARTER                             40.0  
OUNCE                              125.0  
GRAM                                 8.0
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks, very clever, is there anyway to repeat the weights instead of a new duplicate column?

Comment: That’s just a print thing.